# No such file or directory ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to [concat](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) 2 mp3 files into one.

I have created a concat.txt file with for example the following in the same folder as the files I'm trying to concat exist:

**concat.txt**

```
file 'some-song1.mp3'
file 'some-song2.mp3'
```

Those mp3 files are in the same directory as this txt file and **I'm already cd'd into this directory**. This directory lives on a volume.

When I run the following:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy combined.mp3
```

I get:

```
Impossible to open 'some-song1.mp3'
concat.txt: No such file or directory
```

I'm on Mac OS X

Comment: it seems like it doesn't like the dashes in the song names. When I remove them, seems to work. How can I get it working with the dashes in place in the song names?

Comment: There is ASCII hyphen-minus: `-`; and there are many other similarly-looking (but non-ASCII) characters, `–` being one of them. Make sure you're using the character that actually appears in the names.

Comment: thank you!  I added the dashes myself because the filenames had spaces in them. So if I added dashes in the filenames and then in that txt file simply copied the name of the file (did a rename, copy name on the file) then not sure how in the world it would be diff

Comment: Interesting, using underscores worked fine instead of minus. Also using spaces instead worked as well.  Just not minus